# How to use IsEnabledChanged event on element inside style?

Tags: wpf, routed-events

I have an element specified inside a style. I need the codebehind to know when `IsEnabled` changes on one of the elements (the `Border` in this simplified example), so initially I just set the event like normal:

```xaml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TypedValueHelper" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         Value="Markdown">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderThing"
                                    IsEnabledChanged="BorderThing_IsEnabledChanged"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then Visual Studio complained at me and I remembered that you can't set events directly on an element in a style, so I fixed it:

```xaml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="BorderThing" TargetType="Border">
        <EventSetter Event="IsEnabledChanged" Handler="BorderThing_IsEnabledChanged"/>
    </Style>
    
    <Style x:Key="TypedValueHelper" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                         Value="Markdown">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border x:Name="BorderThing"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

But now it's telling me `The event 'IsEnabledChanged' is not a RoutedEvent` ☹

How do I get my event?

Comment: Why don't you have a Trigger on the IsEnabled property?

Comment: @Clemens I've hardly used Triggers and I'm not sure exactly how they work but I'll have a go with that when I get back to work tomorrow. It does sound like what I want. Thing is, I have no clue why events have to be RoutedEvents to work in that situation, so I would never have assumed that using a Trigger would work. I can't visualise what's actually happening underneath. Feel free to make an answer if you think this will solve my problem.

Comment: @Clemens Actually I'm really thick. Today I realised all I needed to do was connect the event in codebehind, especially since I was already connecting stuff via codebehind.